# Mapping Complex JSON in Room Database Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-room

I have a complex JSON which I need to parse and store the information that are inside the JSON data into Room database. Is it possible to store the whole JSON in Room? If that is possible I am up for that too. I am using Kotlin. Can anyone guide me to it?
Here's my JSON sample:

`{
  "chapters": [
    {
      "play": "manual",
      "items": [
        {
          "image": "/path/to/image",
          "background": "#ffffff",
          "text": "text to show on image",
          "points": 1,
          "voice": {
            "type": "tts"
          },
          "words": {
            "type": "wav",
            "file": "/path to words file",
            "parts": [
              {
                "word": "text",
                "from": 122,
                "to": 116
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "image": "/path/to/image",
          "background": "#ffffff",
          "text": "text to show on image",
          "points": 1,
          "voice": {
            "type": "wav",
            "file": "/path/to/file"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: It's not a specific question.

Comment: @AlanDeep You have to keep it extracted in phone, then parse the manifest.json file and show each image along with text.
Also remember that, these books may be downloaded as zip or played directly from web. So for each book imported/downloaded into the app, you have to keep it in the local DB. you have to store meta data information like if it's a local book or a remote book, local path or remote root url. The image paths in the manifest json is related to the local extracted path or the remote root url..
This is the direction I got